# Path Collision Error Mongoose Select Subdocument Fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I understand it's an issue with my projection but I don't fully understand what I'm doing wrong as this worked until a recent MongoDB upgrade.

I am using Mongoose and Node.JS.

```
await UserModel.findOne({ username: 'test' }).sort({ createdOn: 1 }).select('username  authorization.type authorization.homepage').exec();
```

My User has an Authorization subdocument inside of it with fields _id, type, createdOn, and homepage.

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with what I am trying to do, any ideas?

I do have a pre find hook that will populate the reference fields in a schema for a model.

I wonder if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Is there an error message? What is the behavior you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

If I get it correctly, aren't you supposed to do population in this example. You mentioned you have a subdocument, called Authorization. Something in the sense:

```
Model.findOne({ username: 'test'})
     //... some other logic
    .populate({ 
        path: 'authorization',
        select: 'type homepage'
    })
    .exec();
```